# Is there any way to modify typescript file generated by "ng generate component"?

Tags: angular

Angular version 16.1.

Is there any .ts template file or something like that for the "ng generate component" command? I would like to modify what it generates, if it is possible.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/schematics

Comment: Creating a new schematic just to add 2 words to the component seems like a great overkill.

Comment: OK, but that's how to do it if you want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the suggested answers is to create a totally new schematic, which in my case is a total overkill and a waste of time.

I just wanted to add one import and extend all generated components with an inheritance for using a base component across my app. **So just adding a few words to the existing template of `ng generate component`**.

There actually is a lot easier solution using a [patch-package](https://github.com/ds300/patch-package)

With this package you can modify another package in your node_modules and keep the changes, without losing them when updating packages.

So, install it according to their guide and then install `@schematics/angular` to register it in your package.json:

```
npm i @schematics/angular --save-dev
```

Apply your changes to the desired schematics template, in my case I modify the typescript component file in the directory:

```
node_modules\@schematics\angular\component\files
```

After adding my custom import and `extends CustomComponent` to the class I save the file.
Then only thing left is to create a patch:

```
npx patch-package @schematics/angular
```

With that the change I made to the @schematics/angular will not be deleted when using `npm install`.

In the future you can also use this command to apply all your patches:

```
npx patch-package
```

That's it. No need to create a whole new schematics, you can edit existing one in few minutes.